# How can I make Xaxis show minutes when I zoom in from Daily data?

Tags: c#, data-visualization

I have my Xaxis set as DateTime.

The data is nicely displayed at first with Dates on xAxis.

But when I zoom in, the Dates remain - I would like it to switch to minutes.

How do I achieve this?

Comment: You can change the IntervalType maybe to hours: `yourCA.AxisX.IntervalType = DateTimeIntervalType.Hours;` and maybe also the `AxisX.LabelStyle.Format` ..

Comment: That set it but does not make it automatic. Is there on OnScaleChanged eent?

Comment: No but there are AxisViewChanged/Changing events you can use.

Comment: I am afraid they do NOT catch it

Comment: What do you mean? They are always called when you scroll or zoom. The `AxisViewChanged` is the one after the fact.